# How to parameterize a Whiskers partial in Node.JS / Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building a test application (just for learning purposes) using Node.JS and Express and Whiskers as the templating engine.  I want to include a navigation bar so that people can quickly reach various pages in my application, and the navigation bar should highlight the curently selected page.

Good.  So I've got `lib/navbar.js` (see below), and it composes the result HTML "manually".  I wanted to invoke a Whisker template to compute the result HTML, but I couldn't figure out how to invoke a Whisker template.

When `navbar` is called, the `res` argument is undefined, so I can't do `res.render(...)`.

`lib/navbar.js`:

```
var NAVBAR = [
    {id: 'home',        href: '/express',          label: 'Home'},
    {id: 'new',         href: '/express/new',      label: 'Create new article'},
    {id: 'articles',    href: '/express/articles', label: 'List articles'},
    {id: 'tags',        href: '/express/tags',     label: 'List tags'},
    {id: 'frontend',    href: '/frontend',         label: 'Frontend'},
];

exports.navbar = function navbar(req, res) {
    var navbar = Object.create(NAVBAR);
    navbar.forEach(function (x) {
        x.active = (x.id == req.currenttab);
    });
    var result = navbar.map(function (x) {
        var s = '<li @ACTIVE@><a href="@HREF@">@LABEL@</a></li>';
        if (x.active) {
            s = s.replace('@ACTIVE@', 'class="active"');
        } else {
            s = s.replace('@ACTIVE@', '');
        }
        s = s.replace('@HREF@', x.href);
        s = s.replace('@LABEL@', x.label);
        return s;
    });
    return result.join("\n");
};
```

Integration into main app:

```
var app = express();
var navbar = require('./lib/navbar');
app.locals.navbar = navbar.navbar;
```

Hm...  It looks as if this was the wrong way to integrate this partial...